Equation for the Logarithmic Spiral from a vertex to the Brocard Point
In the asymmetric n-bug problem in cyclic pursuit, regarding the case where the triangle always remains similar to its original form, the point of collision is the Brocard Point. A paper by Arthur Bernhart mentions that the trajectory of the particle/bug from the vertex of the triangle to the Brocard point is a logarithmic spiral. Polygons of Pursuit - Arthur Bernhart
Can someone help me find the equation for this logarithmic spiral? Such that would be tangent to $AB$ at $A$ and go from $A$ to $P$? Brocard Point diagram

You will probably be interested by this approximation.


Fig. 1 : With the triangle taken as second example in the answer given by @disgraced. I have an error in my code because there should be an agreement on the curves. I will attempt to spot it and correct it in the coming days.

Fig. 2 : Successive position of the points materialized by triangles. Please note the "trend" of these triangles to "equilaterality".
Here is a different point of view.
One can obtain the pursuit curves using a numerical (Runge-Kutta) solver with differential equations expressing plainly the proportionality of the speed vector of the curve(s) with the difference of positions.
Remarks :

For the sake of simplicity, this proportionality is a mere equality.

Instead of managing 3 different systems of two (first order) differential equations, these systems can be gathered into a single "big" system of 6 differential equations.


Here is a program, written in Matlab for the drawing of the curves (see Fig. 1), using the "ode45" routine implementing a version of Runge-Kutta method (Fig. 2, with successive embedded triangles, has been obtained by a modified version of this program) :
 function pursuit;
 clear all;close all;axis equal;axis([0,8,0,8]);hold on;
 T=[1,7,3;2,4,8] ; % Triangle
 I=[1,2,3,1];plot(T(1,I),T(2,I),'k') ;
 sde = @(t,V) SDE(V); 
 ts = 0:0.1:10; % Time slot
 V0=[T(1,:);T(2,:)]' ; % Initial positions ; order x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3
 [~,V] = ode45(sde, ts, V0); % Runge-Kutta solver   
 for k=1:3
    plot(V(:,k),V(:,k+3)); % k=1 for the first point, etc.
 end;
 %
 function pos = SDE(z) ; % Syst. of 6 (first order) diff. equ. 
 xp1 = z(2)-z(1);yp1=z(5)-z(4); % xp1=differential of x1 wrt t
 xp2 = z(3)-z(2);yp2=z(6)-z(5);
 xp3 = z(1)-z(3);yp3=z(4)-z(6);
 pos=[xp1;xp2;xp3;yp1;yp2;yp3];


Yes, this will give me the plot but not the function for the plot.

See the plot I have Hust added. I agree of course with your comment. I just wanted to say that knowing the existence of this kind of tools is important : it can help to make conjectures, to check also theoreticaly obtained results, etc.
